# What are the "Four Vinayas"?

Tags: theravada, commentary

The Mahāpadesa Sutta describes about the "Four Great Authorities (Mahāpadesas)" that a disciple should refer, if any one claims some new thing to be the word of the Budhha.

> [Mahāpadesa Sutta Summary:](https://www2.buddhistdoor.net/dictionary/details/mahapadesa-sutta)
>
> The Buddha tells the monks of the four mahāpadesā to be respected by
> them. If a monks says he has a certain teaching direct from the Buddha
> himself, his statement should be compared with the rest of the Vinaya
> and Dhamma; if these do not agree, it should be rejected; if they do,
> accepted.
>
> The same applies to that which is said to have been learnt from a
> group of monks led by a Thera from a body of senior monks residing in
> a certain place, or from a single senior monk, proficient in the
> Dhamma, the Vinaya, and the Mātikā. A.ii.167ff.; the sutta is
> incorporated in the Mahāparinibbāna Sutta (D.ii.123ff).

Apart from the above four great authorities, Theravadins use another four Authorities called "The Four Vinayas". What are they?

Answer (score 1):

According to the commentary on that sutta (via Ven. Mingun Sayadaw):

- Suttas
- Suttānuloma: the great authorities as described in the Vinaya and in the discourses
- Ācariyavāda/Aṭṭhakathā: the ancient commentaries
- Attanomati: views held by elder bhikkhus